# sql query to show all results with foreign key

Tags: sql

I have 2 primary tables

```
Semesters (Sem_id(PK),Sem_name) 
Modules (Mod_id(PK),Mod_Name,Unit_id)
```

And a table called result_summary that keeps foreign keys from semesters and modules

```
(Res_sum_id(PK),Sem_id(FK),Mod_id(FK))
```

Final table Semester_Results enters the grades for a student in a particular module which took place in a particular semester

```
(Sum_res_id(PK),Res_sum_id(FK),Student_id(FK),Grade_id(FK))
```

and I write the below query

```
select m.Mod_id,m.Mod_Name, s.semester_name,g.Grade_id
from exa_modules m, exa_grades g, exa_semesters s, exa_results_summary rs,
exa_semester_results sr
where m.Mod_id=rs.Mod_id
and rs.Res_sum_id=sr.Res_sum_id
and s.Sem_id=rs.Sem_id
and sr.grade_id=g.grade_id
and student_id=3
group by rs.semester_id
```

The above query gives a result but does not display more than 1 module result in one semester.

For eg. Student 1 gave two modules in same semester but get only one module result

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use sqlfiddle, and show your results,  i have started some stuff for you here -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c3df/1

Comment: Hello, Thank you for starting the query on sqlfiddle. I have updated the schemas and inserted data for a better view of the query. It is showing exactly the same result that I get also tried with grouping semester and module but no luck.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2a66/7

Comment: Actually, I got this right, I simply did group by rs.res_sum_id. Thanks for the suggestions and your time though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the semester AND the module the student took classes for...  Otherwise it takes only the first one from all records based on one semester.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get other rows with the same query. However, (I have also posted a new question regarding this) the results are showing with separate rows in separate view.

Here is the query I used:

```
select m.unit_id,m.module_name,g.grade_short, s.semester_name
from exa_modules m, exa_grades g, exa_semesters s, exa_results_summary rs, exa_semester_results sr
where m.module_id=rs.module_id
and rs.result_sum_id=sr.result_sum_id
and s.semester_id=rs.semester_id
and sr.grade_id=g.grade_id
and user_id=3
group by rs.result_sum_id, rs.semester_id
order by s.semester_id
```